# Scrapy does not extract the text in certain selectors

Tags: scrapy

I am crawling a website using Scrapy but when I select certain selectors, it does not extract the text in them.

The website is https://www.chopo.com.mx/estudios/super-quimica-de-35-elementos/#

and the selectors that are not extracting the text are:

```
response.css('#informacionmedicos').get()
response.css('#divsinonimos').get()
```

Both of them show the respective html lines of code but I can not see the text that appears in the DOM (not in the html line nor using the ::text attribute). Any ideas what's happening?

Thanks

Comment: there is not any text in them, to confirm `response.xpath('//*[@id="informacionmedicos"]//text()')
` returns empty

Comment: @wishmaster Correct. When you write that xpath or css selector, it appears as blank, but if I look at the DOM, there is text (Ayuno de 12 horas). I am not sure why it does not identifies it.

Comment: @wishmaster Check out the DOM path div #accordion2 div #collapse_2_2 #informacionmedicos

Answer (score 2):

Scrapy doesn't work with rendered DOM but with plain source HTML instead. You can get it using `Ctrl+U` in most of browsers. You'll find this fragment:

```
<div class="panel-body" id="informacionmedicos"></div>
```

As you can see **the information you need is loaded dynamically using JavaScript**. You can try to emulate this JavaScript request or use Scrapy-Splash or similar.

To emulate Javascript you need to send a POST request:
[image]

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. Two questions: How can I see the source using Chrome (no luck with Ctrl + U)? How can I emulate a javascript request?

Comment: @Peretz "View page source" after right click in Chrome (but by default it's `Ctrl+U`)